# How to return concatenated list of IDs when another column values are filtered?

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have a table with 2 columns client_id and client_name. There is a slicer with client_name and the users can multiselect values. How do I  create a measure that concatenates client_ids for all the client_names selected?

| client_id | client_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Australia |
| 2 | Europe |
| 3 | USA |
| 4 | Dubai |

When USA and Dubai are selected in slicer - the expected result of measure is 3,4

```
Measure_client_id_list =
VAR UniqueIDs =
     SELECTCOLUMNS ( 
       FILTER (
               'Table1', Table1 [client_name] = SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[client_name])
),
"CCID", Table1 [client_id]
)
RETURN
CONCATENATEX (
FILTER (
'Table1',
Table1 [client_id] IN Unique IDs
),
Table1 [client_id],
","
)
)
```

Failing when multiple client_names are selected.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a *question* in your question.

Comment: @zabop: Apologies for any ambiguity in the question. I'm looking to create a measure that returns list of IDs (separated by ,) when corresponding client names are selected in the slicer. Please help me with needful DAX query.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to help you, I'm not at all competent in the subject. I'm more competent in how to ask good questions on Stackoverflow. Learning this helps me get the most out of this site, and it also enables me to help others through my questions. If you read and closely follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you'll get better at this. Asking here is hard.